# Spring AMQP client auto reconnect but do not consuming resume

Tags: java, spring-boot, rabbitmq, spring-amqp

If We are using spring amqp client which automatically disable amqp client autorecovery properties and it using own autorecovery mechanism.So if i restart one of the cluster node which behind load balancer default spring amqp autorecovery did not work for the cluster, because amqp connection and channel already connected node is restarted spring amqp do not recovery and reconnect again different node.But if there are already connected and consuming queue remain node did not effect that restart node.

For example Our RabbitMQ cluster is consist of  three node behind ELB on AWS inside  autoscaling group using aws_peer_discovery plugin.Our Cluster policy is /       HA Policy       .*      all     {"ha-mode":"all","ha-sync-mode":"automatic","queue-master-locator":"random","queue-mode":"lazy"}        0

Our consumer client running on ECS with 4 task that already connected and consuming our durable and mirrored queue.That means there is only one queue that is durable and mirrored. consume with 4  consumer task.

Out consumer using default Spring AMQP CachingConnectionFactory as following code block

```
@Bean
public CachingConnectionFactory cachingConnectionFactory(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
    return new CachingConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
}

@Bean
public CachingConnectionFactory cachingConnectionFactory(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
    return new CachingConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
}
```

In that situation when a restart a node (with command line  systemctl restart rabbitmq) in there consumers which are connected to this restarted node do not autorecovery properly i saw attempt to connect to the cluster and already connected but did not consume so when i execute rabbitmqctl list_connection show me all connection fine but rabbitmqctl list_consumers show me an absent consumers that has been connected to the restarter node before and restart node up again but consumer did not reconnect another node or the same node and did not consume current queue.

If I change spring ampq client connection to following line that means saying spring ampq no we are using default amqp-client autorecovery mechanisim do not using spring itself and Test same scenario again at this time we do not get same error so when i restart node test our consumer reconnect another node and continueu to consuming.

```
@Bean
public CachingConnectionFactory cachingConnectionFactory(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
    CachingConnectionFactory cachingConnectionFactory =
            new CachingConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
    cachingConnectionFactory.getRabbitConnectionFactory().setAutomaticRecoveryEnabled(true);
    return cachingConnectionFactory;
```

Why spring-amqp did not work properly.I am wondering if we are using cluster behind load balancer we have to using defalt ampq-client autorecovery mechanism or our spring-amqp client code block wrong or absent ??

Comment: As I said in the rabbitmq-users google group; you need to look at the logs for the application that is not behaving as you expect; if you can't figure it out from that, post the logs somewhere such as a github gist or on pastebin.

Answer (score 0):

You could configure a `Recovery BackOff` which can be applied in a listenerContainer configuration. I would recommend using exponential backoff. For publisher interactions, it is a backoff-policy configuration of the rabbitTemplate.

documentation can be found in section 
[3.1.17. Message Listener Container Configuration](https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/reference/html/)

Comment: We do not use RabbitTemplate so just i want to sure below setting solve our issue permenantly because i set this parameter to the CachingConnectionFactory bean it works when i restart any node that is regarless amqp consumer connected to it ot not it.But you are and Gary Russel said me "Turning on autorecovery in the amqp-client won't make any difference" so i should change my connection to the using RabbitTemplate or below configuration safe to reconnect and reconsuming where they left off
    cachingConnectionFactory.getRabbitConnectionFactory().setAutomaticRecoveryEnabled(true);

Comment: So we want to avoid falling this sutiation we have to use RabbitTemplate or above workaround enought to auto recovery and consume resume if any node restarted or removing or rejoin to the current cluster.Because our consumer know as broker hostname that is load balancer hostname which in front of the broker node in AWS.

And We are using AWS peer discovery plugin to make auto cluster our broker inside AWS 

`cachingConnectionFactory.getRabbitConnectionFactory().setAutomaticRecoveryEnabled(true);`